# How can multiple users use the same directory hierarchy for doing git operations?

Tags: git, bash

I have a **.git/config** file that has multiple users defined as:

```
[user]
    name=user1
    email=user1@domain.com
    name=user2
    email=user2@domain.com
    ...
```

This was created by doing:

```
git config --add user.name user1; git config --add user.email user1@domain.com
git config --add user.name user2; git config --add user.email user2@domain.com
```

The users user1, user2, ... will be doing git operations, but never at the same time.

I am using GIT_SSH to be a script that selects the correct information from the ~/.ssh/config file:

```
ARGS=$(awk "/^Host/{flag=0}flag{printf \"-o %s=%s \",\$1,\$2}/Host $GIT_USER_REPO/{flag=1}" ~/.ssh/config)
exec /usr/bin/ssh $ARGS "$@"
```

That part works just fine if I have just one user.

The problem is that I don't know how to configure the **[remote "origin"]** so that the url can support multiple users.  My existing url is specified as just one thing:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://user1@repo.com:1234/the/path
```

How can multiple users use the same directory for doing git operations?

In the worst case, I've considered that the script specified by $GIT_SSH might modify the .git/config file and update the url dynamically.  I'm hoping there is an easier solution. This solution would involve the script doing:

1. Starting from the current directory, search upwards for a .git directory.
2. From the ARGS above, extract an entry that came from the .ssh/config file that is the url value.
3. Update the .git/config to use this url.
4. Change the exec /usr/bin/ssh line to use this value.

Please note that for the purpose of this question, I am not interested in creating separate directories for each user (doing a git clone, then other git operations). The "users" that will be operating on the directory hierarchy are part of cron-based automation scripts and there are many of them.  Having multiple directories for this would be prohibitive in terms of time and space.  I am only interested in knowing if I can use a single directory (with subdirectories) and have multiple users do git operations under the assumption that operations are never overlapping.  Thanks!

Comment: removing username "user1@" from remote specification should solve the problem.

Comment: You don't need to search for `.git`. `git` does that for you already `git rev-parse --git-dir` returns the path to the `.git` directory.

Comment: Removing `user1@` will work if the system username of the user's using this repo matches the remote username correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that what both what @manzur and @etan-reisner says is true.

A little more info: when I look at what the underlying ssh command is, I see:

```
exec /usr/bin/ssh -o User=user1 -o IdentityFile=/path/to/ssh/key -o HostName=repo.com -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/path/to/knownhosts -p <port> repo.com git-receive-pack '/repo/path'
```

So, I see that the user is being specified explicitly via the User=user1 field and not being implicitly picked up with a user1@repo.com entry that precedes the git-receive-pack.  In fact, with such an entry, the git push fails.

My .ssh/config file consists of:

```
Host user1-repo
    User user1
    IdentityFile /path/to/ssh/key
    HostName repo.com
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /path/to/knownhosts
```

You can see from my original awk command above how the above gets incorporated into the exec command above and how it, therefore, explicitly specifies the User, making it unnecessary to have the remote url specify a username in the url.

Many thanks for the pointer!